# Mapping one continuous data range to another nonlinearly

Tags: algorithm, math, mapping

Sorry about the vague title. I'm not sure how to concisely word what I'm about to ask. This is more of a math/algorithms question than a programming question.

In an app that I'm developing, we have a value that can fluctuate anywhere between 0 and a predetermined maximum (in testing it's usually hovered around 100, so let's just say 100). This range of data is continuous, meaning there are an infinite number of possible values- as long as it's between 0 and 100, it's possible.

Right now, any value returned from this is mapped to a different range that is also continuous- from 1000 to 200. So if the value from the first set is 100, I map it to 200, and if the value from the first set is 0, it gets mapped to 1000. And of course everything in between. This is what the code looks like:

```
-(float)mapToRange:(float)val withMax:(float)maxVal{
    // Establish range constants.
    const int upperBound = 1000;
    const int lowerBound = 200;
    const int bandwidth = upperBound - lowerBound;

    // Make sure we don't go above the calibrated maximum.
    if(val > maxVal)
        val = maxVal;

    // Scale the original value to our new boundaries.
    float scaled = val/maxVal;
    float ret = upperBound - scaled*bandwidth;

    return ret;
}
```

Now, what I want to do is make it so that the higher original values (closer to 100) increase in larger increments than the lower original values (closer to 0). Meaning if I slowly start decreasing from 100 to 0 at a steady rate, the new values starting at 200 move quickly toward 1000 at first but go in smaller increments the closer they get to 1000. What would be the best way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Your value `scaled` is basically the `0-100` value represented in the range `0-1` so it's good to work with.  Try raising this to an integer power, and the result will increase faster near `1` and slower near `0`.  The higher the power, the larger the effect.  So something like:

```
float scaled = val/maxVal;
float bent = scaled*scaled*scaled*scaled;  // or however you want to write x^4
float ret = upperBound - bent*bandwidth;
```

Here's a sketch of the idea:
[image]

That is, the span `A to B`, maps to the smaller span `a to b`, while the span `C to D` maps to the larger span `c to d`.  The larger the power of the polynomial, the more the curve will be bent into the lower right corner.

The advantage of using the `0` to `1` range is that the endpoints stay fixed since `x^n=x` when `x` is `0` or `1`, but this, of course, isn't necessary as anything could be compensated for by the appropriate shifting and scaling.

Note also that this map isn't symmetric (though my drawing sort of looks that way), though course a symmetric curve could be chosen.  If you want to curve to bend the other way, choose a power less than 1.